# Magento 2.4 - Getting error on admin grid page for custom module

Tags: magento2.4, custom-admin-grid

I am creating a custom module in magento 2.4 for admin grid.
Tried everything but on grid page getting below error -

```
    Type Error occurred when creating object:
 Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection\Interceptor, Argument 5 passed to 
Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection\Interceptor::__construct() must implement interface 
Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface or be null, string given, called in 
/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
```

My `Collection.php` is as below -

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid;
 
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    


    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\Grid', 'Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid');
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection);
        
    }
}
```

What should I change in `Collection.php`?

Comment: Try to pass null as the 5th argument.

Comment: Can you please post, How?

Comment: first thing do you really need __counstruct function in that class?

Comment: Without __construct function also getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid;
 
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    


    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\Grid', 'Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid');
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface|null $connection
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb|null $resource
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried above code, and run compile and deploy command as well, still same error.

Comment: Remove all the files from generated folder using `rm -rf generated/*;` and run compile and deploy command and then check again.

Comment: Tried this as well but same error.